# Is 'there' a locative complement in this example?

Tags: complements, predicative-complements, locatives

> [1] He was the only one **there**.

In this sentence, 'the only one there' is an example of a predicative complement (subject complement), a predicative nominal. However, inside this noun phrase, we have the adverb 'there' following the noun 'one'.

Let's expand this sentence:

> [2] He was the only one **who was there**.

Now, if we acknowledge the concept of whiz- deletion — which would imply that the relative pronoun 'who' and the finite verb 'was' were removed — and reverse the process, we can see that 'there' is functioning as a locative complement. (I know that some people have different views on complements.)

Is 'there' in Example [1] still a locative complement?

Comment: Thanks, Bill. For peace of mind, would 'there' be a locative complement in Example [2], as it completes the predicate of the relative clause?

Comment: Yes: in [2] "there" is a locative complement of "be". Obligatory items are always complements. Note that in modern grammar locative "there" is a preposition.

Comment: Incidentally, it would be better to use the term 'modifier' for the "there" in [1]. It is locative, of course, but quite a lot of people (and some grammars) call it an adjunct, but that term is best used for modifiers in clause structure.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a complement, but it's certainly locative in both examples.

Comment: @Bill Don’t you mean a modifier in NP structure?

Comment: *There* is an intransitive preposition. A locative one. It is postmodifying the common noun *one*.  So, it’s a Modifier. Some scholars use the term *Adjunct* to refer just to Modifiers of clauses and verb phrases, others use it to refer to any modifier within a phrase or clause. Depends which church you go to, to quote JL.  Preposition phrases, including one-word ones, can freely postmodify nouns.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, quite so. I tacitly corrected it in my second comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Is 'there' in Example [1] still a locative complement?

No. In "He was the only one who was there," "there" is a locative complement of "was." But once you perform whiz-deletion, there's nothing for it to be a locative complement of. Whiz-deletion does not necessarily preserve the syntactic structure of the original relative clause.